# Need to format a string to match any integer

Tags: python

I am searching through a folder of files, and searching the first 25 characters in each filename. But I need the second format to be ANY integer.

```
import os
import glob
import shutil
from datetime import datetime

source_dir = "%%%//%%%//%%%//Downloads"
destination_dir = "%%//%%%%//%%%%//%%%%//%%%"
string_to_match = '{}T1{}00_meteogram'.format(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),)
```

Just need to be able to have any integer in that location in the string.

Comment: How do you do your search? You can use glob `*` and later check for number in there, or you can use regex with `\d+` to have any positive integer in there (specifically: any chain of 1 or more digits)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you trying to parse dates from a filename?